# Timer when App is in Background

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have to display timeout from current Date() to end Date().
But when app is in background, timer doesn't get updated.
I tried BackgroundTask method but that works for only 3min max. 
Any other way ?

```
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: weakSelf, selector: #selector(self.setTimeLeft), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
func setTimeLeft() {
    let timeNow = Date()

    // Only keep counting if timeEnd is bigger than timeNow
    if timeEnd.compare(timeNow as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: timeNow, to: timeEnd)
        guard let day = components.day, let hours = components.hour,let minute = components.minute , let seconds = components.second else { return }
        var dayText = String(day) + "d "
        var hourText = String(hours) + "h "

        // Hide day and hour if they are zero
        if day <= 0 {
            dayText = ""
            if hours <= 0 {
                hourText = ""
            }
        }
        self.countDownTimeLabel.text = dayText + hourText + String(minute) + "m " + String(seconds) + "s"

    } else {
        self.countDownTimeLabel.text = "Game Over!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apps do not run continuously in the background, unless the app explicitly is allowed to (such as an audio player or GPS).  Also, the user won't see the label change if the app is in the background.

I suggest scheduling a local notification for the end of the timer interval. The OS will deliver it to the user at the right time.

In addition, store the target time in NSUserDefaults. When your app launches again, compare that with the current time to determine if you need to update your label.